# String becomes blank when didSelectRowAtIndexPath called

Tags: ios, objective-c, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a custom cell with a property that is an NSString called videoURl. My implementation code looks like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell";
    RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id obj in topLevelObjects) {
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = obj;
                break;
            }
        }


    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.videoThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbNailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSString *stringWithoutPng = [[thumbNailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@""];
    cell.titleLabel.text = stringWithoutPng;
    cell.dateUploadLabel.text = [videoUploadDateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.durationLabel.text = [videoLengthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.viewsLabel.text = [videoViewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.videoURL = [videoURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(cell.videoURL);

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell *cell = (RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *videoURL = cell.videoURL;
    NSLog(videoURL);
    NSLog(@"^videourl");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
}
```

When it logs the urls at the top everything is fine but when it is called at the bottom nothing prints. What am i doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: What about cell, is it nil?  If not can you access text from labels in the cell?

Comment: Is didSelectRowAtIndexPath even being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please replace your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with this given code...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    videoURL = [videoURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(videoURL);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
}
```